# Swing: Start second JPanel, when the first JPanel is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm writing a simple java game and I'm facing this problem:

My different layouts are in different JPanels (1 JPanel for the welcoming page, where I have to press 'start game' and another one with the actuall functionallity)

I start the game from a JFrame

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RType extends JFrame {

    public RType() {

        add(new Welcome());//first panel
        add(new Board());//panel with the game

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(100, 100);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RType();
    }
}
```

obviuosly, this launches the second panel right after the first, and I cant see the first one.
I've tried some stuff, trying to invoke the second panel in the `main` method, when the first panel is clicked that way:

```
RType rt=new RType();
rt.add(new Board()); //in this case add(new Board()); is removed from constructor
```

but it's doing nothing.
how can I solve it?

Comment: you have to use another layout for example `CardLayout`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @nachokk has said, you should be using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead.  It lets you do things like tabs in a browser, but you don't need to make the tabs visible for your game if you don't want to.  You make your welcome "card" visible at first, then when the user clicks you switch to the `Board` "card".

[image]

Comment: i was to slow answering xD

Comment: @tieTYT cardlayout switches to the second JPanel, but the KeyListeners are not reacting to input. any idea why?

Comment: @IAM I'd have to see some code.  Did you add it to the right component?

Comment: @tieTYT the Board Panel has a keyadapter, that sends events to the figure and changes the coordinates. it works separately, that is not the problem. the problem is, when I switch cardlayouts and get into the game, my Board doesn't react to the input. as if it was not focusable, but I've set focusable on true

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend to add directly to the JFrame components, instead use another container as `JPanel` . JFrame default layout is `BorderLayout`, when you add in the way you are adding it always put in the center.

Make something like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout());
mainPanel.add(new Welcome(), "Welcome");
mainPanel.add(new Board(),"Board");
frame.add(mainPanel);
```

Here is a tutorial [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 2):

on first panel of welcome add a button, and apply actionperformed like

```
    JButton myButton = new JButton("Add Component ");
    myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.remove(welcome);
            frame.add(Board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
            }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, both panels will fill up the entire Frame's area. To fix this, you will need to use another layout, such as a GridLayout to structure the areas in which the panels will take up the Frame's area.

You can also go with no layout to hard code the pixel values of where you want the panels to fit in your frame.

EDIT: Based on what you're looking to do, the CardLayout is probably what you'll want to use for your Frame's layout.